# Creating a list of values per item in dictionary in a list

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a very large list containing nested dictionary which also contains many lists. I would like to take values from a subdictionary and store them in a list under a new key in the primary dictionary. This is what I have tried, but the result is not what I want. I suspect an issue with indentation, but I might be wrong. I am pretty new to python.

```
for p in primary_dict:
    list_i_want  = []
    for element in p['list_in_a_dict']:
        for new_element in element['item_for_list_i_want']:
            list_i_want.append(new_element)
```

The main dictionary looks approximately like this. If I do this command:

```
primary_dict[0]['list_in_a_dict]
```

The output is:

```
[{'item_for_list_i_want': ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'],
  'irrelevant': 'details'},
 {'item_for_list_i_want': ['item2', 'item4'],
  'irrelevant': 'other details'}]
```

What I would like is when I enter this command:

```
primary_dict[0][' list_i_want']
```

to have this output:

```
['item1', 'item2', 'item3','item2', 'item4']
```

My dict is a list of other dictionaries, so I also want it for *primary_dict[1][' list_i_want'], primary_dict[2][' list_i_want']*, etc.

Comment: It sounds like your `primary_dict` is actually a list.

Comment: @jfaccioni thanks, corrected terminology :)

Comment: Usually when you get to the point where you have a list of dictionaries of lists, then it's time to think about using OOP. A list of objects (or even a dictionary of objects) is usually much easier to manage IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
result = []
for p in primary_dict:
    temp = {}
    list_i_want  = []
        for element in p['list_in_a_dict']:
            for new_element in element['item_for_list_i_want']:
                list_i_want.append(new_element)
    temp['list_i_want'] = list_i_want
    result.append(temp)
```

This is your desired result?
The result of result[0][list_i_want] will be what you desired.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do list comprehension if you want

```py
your_list = [{'item_for_list_i_want': ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'],
  'irrelevant': 'details'},
 {'item_for_list_i_want': ['item2', 'item4'],
  'irrelevant': 'other details'}]


items = [ 
     item 
     for your_dicts in your_list
     for key, val in your_dicts.items()
     for item in val
     if key == 'item_for_list_i_want'
]
print(items)
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you please also help me with looping it through every dictionary in the list (last sentence in the question body)?